# Pass an intent from an activity to a class extending surfaceview?

Tags: android, android-intent, surfaceview

How do I pass an intent from an activity to a class extending surfaceview?

Heres the code that sends out the intent:

```
btnCutOutter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Send intent to cut image from user selection path
            //See designCanvas.java for details

            String optionSelected = "Yes";
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), designCanvas.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("id",optionSelected );

        }
    });
```

When I try to retrieve the intent data :

```
public class designCanvas extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
//Create shape using Path
    Path mPath = new Path();
    private drawThread _thread;
    private ArrayList<GraphicObject> _graphics = new ArrayList<GraphicObject>();

    public designCanvas(Context context, AttributeSet attributes) {
        super(context, attributes);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        _thread = new drawThread(getHolder(), this); 
        String optionSelected = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");

                                         . . .
```

I am informed by eclipse that :

```
The method getIntent() is undefined
```

I would be very grateful if someone could give me so guidance on this :)

Many thanks.

Comment: Your question does not make much sense, Intents are used solely in an Activity. Why would you need to pass an Intent to a SurfaceView?

Comment: I need to pass an intent into a Surface View as I want to control the outcome of the code within SurfaceView. To define my question further, how would I pass data from one class to another bearing in mind that one of the classes hasn't got an activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any view in an android is contained within an activity, therefore the activity has a reference to the view (in this case a SurfaceView). So its simply a matter of getting the intent data in the Activity then using a setter for the data you want to pass to the SurfaceView

So in the Activity that holds the SurfaceView call getIntent like you have in your question then call a setter in the SurfaceView eg. `mySurfaceView.setSomeValue(someValue)`

**EDIT**

You are calling getIntent() in the designCanvas class it needs to be called in the Activity thats holds SurfaceView

```
public SomeActivity extends Activity{

public void onCreate(Bundle b){
     super.onCreate(b);

     //give that the constructor for your surface view has an attributeset i assume    
     //you are creating it in xml
     designCanvas dc = findViewById(someid);

     String s = getIntent(.getStringExtra("id");
     dc.setId(s);

}
```

Comment: I've tried that. The code for sending the intent seems to be fine. When I attempt to get the intent I am unable to use getIntent() as eclipse states it is undefined. I'll update my question with more detail.

Comment: designCanvas class extending SurfaceView isn't held within an activity. Its just a public class in its own .java file.
However, I have tried to encapsulate the designCanvas class extending SurfaceView within an activity, but unfortunately I end up back where I started lol If I do this, eclipse insists I move designCanvas into its own class. So the code and data I need to access is still out of reach. I really appreciate your patience triggs :)

Comment: @Odhran you're trying to access getIntent() from a SurfaceView. SurfaceView doesn't have that method - only descendants of Activity class have it. You should call getIntent() in your Activity - the one that hosts the  SufraceView, then get the data from intent, then pass it to the SurfaceView. SurfaceView should not ever try to access any intents, SurfaceView is just a UI component, it has no business in handling intents - there are Activities for that exact purpose.

Comment: Odhran yes, eclipse will make you move it to a separate file IF it's the top-level class. To *nest* a class, you have to actually put it between the curly brackets of another class, like a method or a member. But I strongly advise you against doing that, that's bad design. If you do, at least mark it static or you can get all kinds of memory leaks. Even better, leave it in a separate file, create a member of that type in your activity, and use a setter method to pass data to it, as @triggs suggests.

Comment: If its not held within an activity its never going to be shown, if its declared in an xml file then you can get a reference from by using findViewById as shown above. maybe this can shed some light on your your problem (its just an example of one use of surfaceview) http://www.droidnova.com/playing-with-graphics-in-android-part-ii,160.html

Comment: Ok I understand what you mean now. Took me a while!lol
Thanks Ivan Bartsov for your comments and thanks for your comments and the link triggs. I'll read up on that now :)